# Why does JavaFX use “static” constructors?

Tags: java, oop, javafx, static-factory

In JavaFX, there are a few classes, for example javafx.scene.text.Font and javafx.scene.paint.Color that have static methods that act like constructors. In the Font class, it is possible to create a new Font object with the statement `new Font(name, size)`, but it is equivalent to calling the static method `Font.font(name, size)`, where the Font.font method returns the reference to a new Font object. What are the objective benefits that JavaFX gains from creating these ‘static’ constructors? They seem redundant. Why not just declare more overloaded constructors to achieve the same goal?

Comment: This is Item 1 in Joshua Bloch's *"Effective Java"*.

Comment: Factory methods have few advantages over constructor. For instance they are *not required* to return *new* instance each time, but can cache previously created and returned results and for same parameters return same already created object. Try to see if that is the case, for instance with code like `System.out.println(Font.font(name, size) == Font.font(name, size))`. Just use same `name` and `size` in both sides.

Comment: @JohnKugelman It's a reasonable question in the general sense, just not one that fits this site. It's not a "specific programming question" but a question about software design, which is likely to draw opinions and discussion.

Comment: I heartily disagree. This is a specific question about particular classes, not an opinion poll about the design pattern in general. One could quite reasonably write an answer that peeks at the source code for `javafx.scene.text.Font` and `javafx.scene.paint.Color` and explains what the static methods do and why the same thing could not be accomplished with constructors. Or an answer could dig up design rationale for JavaFX as a whole where the library designers explain why JavaFX uses static constructors throughout.

Comment: Asking about the specific design choices of a library is off-topic as it is considered opinion-based.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I agree that based on what you just wrote, looking for “design rationale”, this question belongs on [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), see [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-software-engineering).

Comment: OK, so let me attempt an answer that is as specific as possible.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-factory/info for a concise and authoritative explanation of Static Factory Methods in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, there are several advantages and disadvantages to using static factory methods compared to using constructors. A good reference for this is Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" (which I strongly recommend any Java programmer should read); in the second and third editions it is Item 1.

For the specific classes you mention:

### `Color`

Since factory methods have names, using factory methods allows for multiple methods with the same signature. E.g.

```
public static Color color(double red, double green, double blue);
public static Color hsb(double hue, double saturation, double brightness);
```

These could not be replaced by two different constructors, as they would be ambiguous.

Additionally, it could be argued that the factory methods provide more descriptive names. For example, the two methods

```
public static Color valueOf(String value);
public static Color web(String colorString);
```

have exactly the same functionality, but both are valuable from a design perspective. The `valueOf()` method allows for interaction with the `FXMLLoader`, whereas the `web(...)` method is more appropriately named (it takes a string in the same format as is used in the HTML specification).

### `Font`

The rationale for this class is less clear, and knowing the exact reasons would require knowing the mind of the original API designers. However, note that the [API specification](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Font.html) of the static factory method differs from the constructor:

```
public static Font font(String family, double size)
```

> Searches for an appropriate font based on the font family name and size. This method is not guaranteed to return a specific font, but does its best to find one that fits the specified requirements. A null or empty value for family allows the implementation to select any suitable font.

```
public Font(String name, double size)
```

> Constructs a font using the specified full face name and size

As far as I can tell, the current implementation is actually the same, but the API specification allows for that to change in future releases. There may be other benefits too, e.g. the static factory method *could* cache fonts and return the same instance if that were determined to be a performance enhancement.